# Do we need to have exchange and Sharepoint installed on same server to sync to outlook

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, outlook, profile-sync

How do we sync SharePoint 2013 with outlook 2013? Do we need to have exchange and SharePoint 2013 installed on the same server? I am having problems when I click on Sync to look. what are the steps needed to sync.

Comment: What are you trying to sync, tasks?

Comment: do you want to sync task, calendar or document library? what error you are getting? please share details or screen shot.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not (ever) install SharePoint and Exchange on the same server, it will most likely break the installation.

I'm not sure what you are trying to sync, but if it is the synchronization of task that was new for 2013 you find a very detailed guide here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554516.aspx

Comment: I am trying to sync task list of sharepoint 2013 with outlook 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can conifgure the Task Sync between SharePoint 2013 & Outlook 2013. You just need to follow the steps mentioned below.

Pre-requisite

- You need to enable the Offline Synchronization for External Lists
  option, which is disabled by default and deactivate the Minimal
  Download Strategy option, which is enabled by default. To do this
  SharePoint site owner needs to login to SharePoint site and navigate
  to Settings > Site Settings > Manage site features. Click Activate
  next to Offline Synchronization for External Lists. Click Deactivate
  next to Minimal Download Strategy, and confirm the warning about
  deactivation.
- While you can add to, edit or delete items in Contacts, Tasks or
  Calendar, you can only edit items in the Documents Library. It is not
  possible to add or remove documents from the SharePoint Document
  Library via Outlook 2007/2010/2013.
- Prior to connecting SharePoint Contacts, Tasks, Calendar or Document
  Library to Outlook 2007/2010/2013, we recommend that you configure a
  Microsoft Exchange account in Outlook 2007/2010/2013 for the user.
- Make sure that the user is granted sufficient access permissions to
  SharePoint Contacts, Tasks, Calendar or Document Library.

Now follow the instruction over here: [How Do I Synchronize SharePoint 2013 Contacts, Tasks, Calendar or Document Library With Outlook 2007/2010/2013?](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=2429)

Also watch this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCGDISZgJJg